# JQuery animate is not working correctly

Tags: jquery, css

I have been trying to lean JQuery in the past few weeks, i wanted to test make a "roulette" animation with JQuery but i have a problem.

I have made this JQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#roll").click(function(){
        $(".imageBox").animate({left: '250px'});
    });
});
```

But it is not working for some reason, and when i change

```
$(".imageBox").animate({ left: '250px' });
```

to

```
$(".rouletteBox").animate({ left: '250px' });
```

It works for some reason but I don't want it to be like that.

Here is my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L7esjkzL/

On that JSFiddle you can see that if you change `.imageBox` to `.rouletteBox` the animation works.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vdu2eren/ if u use left u have also to use postion:absolute / fixed

Comment: You can't set left prop on static possition element, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Try add ` position:relative;` to your class  `.imageBox` https://jsfiddle.net/L7esjkzL/2/

Comment: @mr.void position: absolute / fixed removed the other `<div class="imageBox"></div>` and left only one box there, i tested with `position: inherit;` and that worked. Thanks!

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen `position: relative;` worked also ! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `left` value to be respected you need to set the `position` to something other than the default of `static`, eg `relative`:

```
.imageBox {
    /* other rules... */ 
    position: relative;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L7esjkzL/3/)